# Want to Run only match id links on other html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**anchor_example1.html**

This is firts page  code

```
h1>Menu page</h1> 

<h2>Anchor example</h2>

<h3><a name="menu">Menu</a></h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="anchor_example2.html#a001">Jump to a001</a></li>
<li><a href="anchor_example2.html#a002">Jump to a002</a></li>
<li><a href="anchor_example2.html#a003">Jump to a003</a></li>
</ul>
```

**anchor_example2.html**

This is second page code

```
<h1>Target page</h1>

<h2>Anchor example</h2>

<h3><a name="a001">a001</a></h3>
<p>paragraph text ...</p>

<h3><a name="a002">a002</a></h3>
<p>paragraph text ...</p>

<h3><a name="a003">a003</a></h3>
<p>paragraph text ...</p>

<hr>
```

When i click  on first href link it open all other also on second page .but i  want that it run according to specified id #a001  example when first href link select on for example.

```
<li><a href="anchor_example2.html#a001">Jump to a001</a></li>
```

. then it run only first section on second page and all other will hide.

```
<h3><a name="a001">a001</a></h3><p>paragraph text ...</p>
```

Comment: Which server side scripting language are you using?

Comment: Do you want to completely hide all the other sections other than the anchored one in the second page? Or do you want to just scroll to the anchor point you specify by the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a jquery based solution which will entirely hide the other sections rather than the section you specify by the url, the below solution works.

**anchor_example1.html**

```
<h1>Menu page</h1> 
<h2>Anchor example</h2>
<h3><a name="menu">Menu</a></h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="anchor_example2.html#a001">Jump to a001</a></li>
<li><a href="anchor_example2.html#a002">Jump to a002</a></li>
<li><a href="anchor_example2.html#a003">Jump to a003</a></li>
</ul>
```

**anchor_example2.html**

```
<h1>Target page</h1>
<h2>Anchor example</h2>
<div class="content" name="a001">
    <h3><a>a001</a></h3>
    <p>paragraph text ...</p>
</div>
<div class="content" name="a002">
    <h3><a>a002</a></h3>
    <p>paragraph text ...</p>
</div>
<div class="content" name="a003">
    <h3><a>a003</a></h3>
    <p>paragraph text ...</p>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content").hide();
        var currentUrl = window.location.href;
        var anchorVal = currentUrl.split("#")[1];
        $('.content[name='+anchorVal+']').show();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you! :) If it solves your issue accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify it by `id` instead `name`